# Conditional responses in Laravel Eloquent API resources

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5.7. I have a model `Audio`, with the fields `id` and `title`. An `Audio` can have many `AudioVersion`s, where `AudioVersion` has `id`, `audio_id` (referring to `Audio`) and `url`.

Now, I have two parent models, `Foo` and `Bar`, which can have many `Audio` models.

**Audio:**

```
class Audio extends Model
{
    public function versions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AudioVersion', 'audio_id');
    }
}
```

**AudioVersion:**

```
class AudioVersion extends Model
{
    public function audio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AudioContent');
    }
}
```

**Foo:**

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function audioContents()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Audio', 'audio_contentable', 'audio_contentable');
    }
}
```

I have an Eloquent API resource, `FooResource`, which returns its `Audio` objects:

**FooResource:**

```
class FooResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'audio' => AudioResource::collection($this->audioContents),
        ];
    }
}
```

**AudioResource:**

```
class AudioResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'urls' => $this->versions,
        ];
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the `audio` key of my `FooResource` I only want to return `Audio`s which have `AudioVersions` related to them. I.e. if I have an `Audio` with no `AudioVersions`, I do not want that `Audio` included in the `Foo`'s `audio` key. I can't find a way to do this deep conditional logic in Eloquent / Resources.

Comment: Would it have something to do with adding a `where()` query to `$this->audioContents`? Then you could query whether it has `$this->versions->count()` before passing it into the `AudioResource::collection()`.

Comment: If this works, it would read better if you were to `filter()` the collection by those with `$this->versions->count()` rather than`where()`.

Comment: Thanks @thisiskelvin - I guess my problem is knowing where to add this `where` logic...

Comment: I've added my answer below, let me know if clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I added a scope to `Audio`:

```
public function scopeHasVersions($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('versions');
}
```

Then in `FooResource`:

```
return [
    'audio' => AudioResource::collection($this->audioContents()->hasVersions()->get()),
];
```

Comment: This looks better actually.

Answer (score 1):

In the `FooResource` class, you could `filter()` the collection before passing it to the collection method.

```
class FooResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $audioContents = $this->audioContents()->filter(function($audio, $key) {
            return $audio->versions->count();
        }

        return [
            'audio' => AudioResource::collection($audioContents),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the end I went a different route (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52312189/)). I can't say which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this. This is the example, you only need to add join inside `with` so that only those `audios` will be fetched which have `audio versions`.

```
$audioContents = AudioContents::with([
    'audio' => function ($query) use ($SpecificID) {
        return $query->join("audio_versions")
                    ->on("audio_versions.audio_id", "=", "audios.id");
    }
])->get();
```

Try this and let me know if you are facing any issue.